# In Swift 5, How can i check if the input 2d array [[Int]] is matrix M x M not M x N

Tags: swift

I have an input arr: [[Int]]
How can i check if this arr is M x M

So, it should looks like:

[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]

not to be M x N such as:

[1,2,3]
[4,5]
[6,7,8,9]

I have tried arr.count but it return 3 in the previous two cases,
because it return the number of sub arrays not its their counts too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check if all “inner” arrays have the same length as the “outer” array. This is conveniently done with the [`allSatisfy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2996794-allsatisfy) method:

```
func isSquareMatrix<T>(_ m: [[T]]) -> Bool {
    let dim = m.count
    return m.allSatisfy { $0.count == dim }
}
```

Example:

```
print(isSquareMatrix([[1, 2, 3], [3, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])) // true
print(isSquareMatrix([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]])) // false
```

The above function is *generic* so that it can be used with arbitrary element types, not only with `[[Int]]`:

```
print(isSquareMatrix([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]])) // true
```

Comment: @Sulthan: I would say yes: a square matrix of dimension zero.

Comment: So I'd assume `allSatisfy` follows the *lazy* check approach since if the first predicate returns false the iteration should stop, correct?

Comment: @AhmadF: Correct. `allSatisfy` was introduced in Swift 4.2 with https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0207-containsOnly.md as a convenience method for `!contains {!predicate($0) }`

Comment: Thanks a lot,  its totally answered my question.